# Left join with propel 2.0

Tags: php, propel

I have to do this query with propel's code:

```
$sql = "SELECT dt.id_ditta,dt.rag_soc as nome_pagina
                            FROM utente_ditte ud    
                            LEFT JOIN ditte dt 
                            ON  ud.id_ditte  = dt.id_ditta 
                            WHERE ud.id_users=:user";
                $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute(array(':user' => $_SESSION['id_user']));
                $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now I do with custom query, but I want to improve it,
I have seen that I can use `->leftJOIN()` but i don't know to apply it.
***How i can do this?***

Sorry if my question is with few details, i'm newbie.

Comment: Propel is kind of abandonware. My advice is to go with Doctrine.

Comment: what's do you mean with "abandonware"?

Comment: it's not developed anymore, or kind of. They tried a big rewrite to take it to the same level of Doctrine, but they missed the train. And it's really a pity, since I really loved Propel some years ago

Comment: Have a look at the question on [joining unrelated tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890036/propel-orm-joining-unrelated-tables/24356593), it might shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

If you have build the model with Propel 2 (or Propel 1), you can write code like this:

```
$collection = UtenteDitteQuery::create()
                  ->leftJoinDitte()
                  ->filterByIdUsers($_SESSION['id_user'])
                  ->find();
```

Comment: Note that this requires that you define your relation in your schema

Comment: not working, i do var_dump($collection); and not give me a correct array.